# Importing Facebook events into Calendar on Mac

Tags: macos, facebook

iOS 6.0 brought iOS calendar syncing with Facebook, which is very convenient. I can see all my Facebook events on my iPhone.

Is there a similar functionality for OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion? Or is there any other way to import my Facebook events into my OS X Calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can export my upcoming events to iCal in Facebook. These are the steps that I follow:

1. Open up https://www.facebook.com/events/calendar
2. Click on the cog-wheel icon in the upper right corner (shown in the image below)
   [image]
3. Click `Export`. A Facebook prompt window will appear with the following text:

   > You can export your friends' birthdays or upcoming events into Apple iCal, Microsoft Outlook and Google Calendar.
4. Click on `upcoming events`. Now iCal will open with a window where you can insert a calendar URL to which you want to subscribe. Leave the filled in text field as is and click on `Subscribe`.
5. Now you will have all your upcoming events in iCal.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently there is no support for that. The closest thing is Facebook birthdays by syncing your contacts with facebook and then enabling the Birthdays calendar.